# Changing position of uitextfield in the uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I use This one to try to change the position but nothing happends

```
    CGRect frame=timeSpentField.frame;//uitextfield
    frame.origin.y-=100;
    timeSpentField.frame=frame;
```

What should i do?

Comment: If your using auto layout you should change the constraint as opposed to changing the frame

Comment: Generic question: are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yeah the problem was auto layout. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For future programmers with this problem, make sure to always check whether or not you're using auto layout (whether on purpose or by accident). It will stop you from being able to change frame in most instances.